# Weird Shortcuts problem on iOS 15 and WatchOS 8

Tags: automation, sirishortcuts, ios15, watchos-8

I have an app which allow users to create shortcuts for it. It worked well on my iPhone and my Apple Watch until I upgrading my devices to iOS 15 and WatchOS 8.0

It keep asking me "Allow *** to share data with (null)" every time even after I said "allow"

I googled but only found one post who had the similar problem
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/shortcuts-to-web-open-in-chrome-bug.2312693/

did my own tests and created a new Twitter “What is happening” shortcut on my iPhone, it always ask me “All See what’s happening” to share data with (null)” just like what happened to our watch app on an Apple watch (WatchOS 8 )
I used the same Twitter shortcut too on my Apple Watch and first time it asked the same question then it shows “Can’t send data to (null)” for the second time.

I guess it is a new system bug but I am not sure.
Does anybody have a clue about how to solve it? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior on different apps. Seems to be some iOS/WatchOS-related bug, not app-specific. That updated introduced some significant changes on privacy mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

I know how to fix this! If you go to your shortcuts and change the browser in the action to safari it will stop displaying the prompt. The browser that opens will still be chrome as long as you have it set as your default browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my own shortcuts has nothing to do with web browser also my default web browser is Safari

Comment: @echo seeing same thing with my app remote4mac.app... haven't found what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an iOS bug which seems to be fixed in the latest iOS 15.1 beta 3 release.

You can either install the beta — if you have access to it — or wait for the final release of iOS 15.1.

Answer (score 0):

In settings > Privacy > HomeKit I disabled the toggles for the apps eWeLink, Mi Home, Smart Life and Tuya Smart (The shortcuts of the apps which showed this popup in my apple watch)

After that this popup appeared only once and after clicked allow, This annoying pop up stopped appearing for my shortcuts in apple watch.

Update:

You can enable the toggles in settings > Privacy > HomeKit after allowing the first allow prompt for shortcuts in Apple watch. After enabling HomeKit toggles again Apple watch shows this "Allow to share data with (null)" only once for shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I didn't use HomeKit. My scenario is to add a Shortcuts from my app.